# Magento Installation Without .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I'm making a new Magento Installation and like always, access magento.com to download the installations files.

For my surprise, theres no more .htaccess in the compress files O.o

Someone can tell why or give any tip?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

It is always there, but it's a hidden file so just change the setting of the Files Manager or Finder to see it.

[image]